# SQL - Adding/Disabling a Where clause based on a boolean condition in Select Statement (ASP.net SQLDataSource)

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

I have a SQL select statement that is basically just

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE status != 5
```

It is a lot more complex than in reality, but its mostly convoluted column names and joins.

what i want to be able to do is on a parameter being a value, I disable the where clause, i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
where CASE WHEN @parameter = 'true'
THEN --...add the where clause ('status != 5')
```

It doesn't work like that but does anyone have a different method of approach? i'm using ASP.net with the select in an SQLDatasource if that opens up any options. It's to do with hiding particular records from non-logged in users but showing others.

**TL;DR:** Can I enable/disable a where clause based on a parameter in SQL or ASP.net

Comment: You can just write `WHERE @parameter != 'true' OR status != 5`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do literally what you're asking (i.e. disable the where clause) using dynamic sql.

```
declare @ssql varchar(max)
set @ssql = 'SELECT * FROM myTable' 
+ CASE WHEN @parameter = 'true' THEN ' WHERE status != 5' ELSE '' END
EXEC (@ssql)
```

However, it will be easier to read and modify in future if you can avoid dynamic sql.

Since you need to filter status where param = true, but when param = false you don't want to filter on status, your where clause should look like this:

```
WHERE (@parameter=True AND status!=5) OR (@parameter=false)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following will work perfectly in your situation without any use of dynamic SQL.  This is based on an assumption that `status` value can never take on a value of `-1`. You would need to come up with a similar value in your situation that status will never ever equal.

When @parameter is true then the query is like this: `SELECT * FROM myTable where status !=5`, but when @parameter is false, then the below query acts like this query: `SELECT * FROM myTable  where status != -1` which is effectively returning all records as if the the where clause is not there *since the condition `status != -1` is always true*.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
where status != CASE WHEN @parameter = 'true' THEN 5 else -1 END
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the condition inn where clause..

```
declare @parameter varchar(10)
set @parameter ='true'

SELECT * FROM myTable 
where  @parameter = 'true' and status != 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use dynamic query

```
declare @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT * FROM myTable'
IF (@parameter = 1)
SET @query += N' WHERE (status <> 5)'

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```